# Script for checking server side runtime

Tags: server-side, sniffing

Netcraft is able to get statistics for millions of sites what web technology (PHP, ASP.NET, Java Servlet etc.) they are using on their servers. I was wondering how they do that from the outside and whether there is some script that can be used to check the server side technology for a random site?

Answer (score 0):

They get a lot of information via the HTTP HEAD, other data from the whois registry, the uptime (I guess) from finger. See more on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Web_Application_Fingerprint_%28OWASP-IG-004%29 - netcraft is mentioned at the very bottom of that page.

Comment: Yes, I know about the HTTP header but the Server one is not always returned. In addition the Server header doesn't contain information about the technology - such info is contained in X-Powered-By which is non-standard header, and thus not guaranteed to be returned at all. Any other ideas?